# Python Selenium XPath Traceback Error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting an error with selenium's find_element_by_xpath. This is the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/iyadschool/Desktop/q_hack.py", line 15, in <module>
    text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), ' " + term[1] + "')]")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 354, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 832, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 297, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[contains(text(), ' indifference')]"}
  (Session info: chrome=64.0.3282.186)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528157 (4429ca2590d6988c0745c24c8858745aaaec01ef),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.6 x86_64)
```

Here is the piece of code that the error is pointing to:

```
term = ["impalpable", "indifference", "complacent", "transpire", "abject", "derivative", "derive", "dispel", "authentic", "deprived", "aesthetic", "affinity", "depict", "impertinent", "inevitable", "deviate", "aggrandize", "aggregate"]
definition = ["unable to be felt", "lack of concern", "self-satisfied", "to happen", "miserable", "unoriginal", "to get\
come from", "to drive away", "real", "take away something", "pertaining to beauty", "a natural attraction or feeling of kinship", "To give a picture of; to describe", "rude and disrespectful", "unavoidable", "depart, from a path or plan", "to increase in power, influence, and reputation", "(v.) - to gather, amass"]

termnumb = len(term)
defnumb = len(definition)

text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), ' " + term[1] + "')]")
text.click()
```

I don't know what is going on? I am trying to make a code that gets the first term and definition from the list. Then it clicks on both of them on the page and goes to the next term. I want to find the element by the text between the tags ( term name )

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Share HTML source code (page URL) for the same

Comment: it's quizlet.com. I am failing class right now and quizlet is my only chance to get a passing grade. @Andersson

Comment: If this is for a class, then we shouldn't be giving you the answer.  But we can give you pointers.  Look carefully at the error message 
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[contains(text(), ' indifference')]"} then look at the page.  is there an element that contains the text ' indifference'?  (read that string in the quotes VERY carefully...computers will only do what you tell them to do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using contains(), provide the bare minimum to ensure a unique text match. Hint: any extraneous characters can bite you.

Try your locator out in the browser using the console in the dev tools. $$("css selector here") or $x("xpath here"). If it returns your element, you're locked and loaded. If not, adapt and overcome.

Here is another useful method of troubleshooting:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'derive')]")
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
text.click()
```

It will drop you into your script just before the click, with all the variables intact. Try running `element.click()` manually, and watching what happens on your page. Clicks can be finicky, you may have to try clicking with offset, or in extreme cases executing a javascript snipped to click (I've found this is rare and a last resort).

Comment: I put - $x("//div[contains(text(), 'derive')]") - in the console and the output was - [div]. Is this correct? When I run the code again, it still doesn't click the div. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: I tried but unfortunately, I don't have the rep to do so.